# How do I structure my if text then colour statement

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to match products with prices.

There are 5 different products named as; "green", "red", "blue", "black" and "brown" and their corresponding prices are £10, £10, £10, £10 and £5 respectively.

Suppose the current input product is "green" in cell B15 then the price £10 will automatically be assigned to cell F15. 
I want to achieve this for any new data I put into the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Build a table of your products.  Place the product names on the left and the prices on the right.  Use a VLOOKUP function in F15 to find the price from the table based on the product selection in B15.  For the example below the VLOOKUP formula is as follows:

```
=IF(B15="","",VLOOKUP(B15,$D$9:$E$13,2))
```

The VLOOKUP function is wrapped inside the if function so that nothing is displayed as long as cell B15 is blank.  You could also wrap it in an IFERROR function  to display NOT FOUND, blank or 0 for those occasions where something is entered in B15 that is not in the list.  You can also use data validation on cell B15 and set it to a list option then set the list to be your first column.  This will provide a pick list, prevent typos and prevent entries that are not a part of you table.

[image: POC]

Data validation list

[image: Validation demo]